# Переменные класса

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток) 
Есть программа которая находить максимальное число массива.

```
public class Maximum {

public static double max(double [] distance){

    double [] dist = distance;
    double max = dist[0];
    for (int i = 0; i > dist.length; i++){
        if (dist[i] > max){
            max = dist[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Макксимум класса = " +max);

    return max;
}

}
```

Нужно занести это число (max) в переменную и вызвать ее в другом классе. Задание детское, но я Уже битый час ломаю голову, но ничего не получается((( 
Подскажите как это сделать?)

Answer (score 3):

Весьма странная задача, но если Вы уж так хотите:

```
public class Maximum {
    private double mMax;

    public void max(double [] distance){

        double [] dist = distance;
        double max = dist[0];
        for (int i = 0; i > dist.length; i++){
            if (dist[i] > max){
                max = dist[i];
            }
        }
        mMax = max;
    }

    double getMax() {
        return mMax;
    }
}
```

Где-то в другом класса:

```
double[] array = {10, 2, 5, 100.2};
Maximum maximum = new Maximum();
maximum.max(array);
double max = maximum.getMax();
```

Ну а вообще, у Вас метод `max` объявлен как `static`, следовательно, где-то в другом классе можно просто сделать так (при Вашей реализации класса `Maximum`):

```
double[] array = {10, 2, 5, 100.2};
double max = Maximum.max(array);
```

Comment: Вот в этой строчке заморочка) Оно то Mmax не видит, то max не видит. А Через метод не могу вызвать, так как у меня там все закручено))

Comment: Maximum.max(Distance.distance(Etalon.etalonMatrix(ConvertToMatrix.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.image("Images\\1.jpg"))),
                ConvertToMatrix.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.image("Images\\1.jpg"))));

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос сводится к вызову метода из другого класса, поскольку там нужно вычисленное значение.
Вот второй класс, который получает значение максимума и выводит его.

```
public class SeeMaximum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      double [] a = new double[] {2.4, 5.8, 1.5};
      double max = Maximum.max(a);
      System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это мне не подходит, так как у меня программа побольше и там много методов связаны.

Comment: Maximum.max(Distance.distance(Etalon.etalonMatrix(ConvertToMatrix.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.image("Images\\1.jpg"))),
                ConvertToMatrix.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.image("Images\\1.jpg"))));

Answer (score 1):

> Есть программа которая находить максимальное число массива.

Увы, метод данной программы не находит максимальное значение массива, так как условие цикла записано не верно.

```
public static double max(double [] distance){

    double [] dist = distance;
    double max = dist[0];
    for (int i = 0; i > dist.length; i++){
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (dist[i] > max){
            max = dist[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Макксимум класса = " +max);

    return max;
}
```

Правильней было бы записать функцию по крайней мере следующим образом

```
public static double max(double [] distance){

    double [] dist = distance;
    double max = dist[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < dist.length; i++){
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (dist[i] > max){
            max = dist[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Макксимум класса = " +max);

    return max;
}
```

Чтобы записать результат работы этой функции в переменную вы можете в main, например, записать

```
double max = Maximum.max( someArray );
```

Затем передать эту переменную некоторому методу другого класса в качестве аргумента

```
OtherClass obj = new OtherClass();
obj.someMethod( max );
```

Если же поле другого класса вообще открыто для доступа извне, то вы можете записать

```
OtherClass obj = new OtherClass();
obj.someField = max;
```

Comment: Чтобы вызывать методом мне нужно вот такое написать:  double max = Maximum.max(Distance.distance(Etalon.etalonMatrix(ConvertToMatrix.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.image("Images\\1.jpg"))),
            ConvertToMatrix.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.image("Images\\1.jpg"))));

Comment: а это не то что мне нужно))

Comment: @ДашаНовикова  Совершенно не понял, причем здесь то, какое выражение вы используете для вызова метода?

Comment: Просто таким выражением у меня вызывается много лишнего, к примеру метод ConvertToMatrix выводит матрицу, а Etalon массив. Но мне нужно лишь чтобы вывело число (max), которое потом мне нужно будет сравнить с другим числом.

Comment: @ДашаНовикова Опять ничего не понял. Вызывайте метод, используя другой аргумент. Какие проблемы?

Comment: У меня каждый метод использует предыдущие методы в качестве параметров. Они все связаны)

Comment: @ДашаНовикова Тогда совершенно не понятно, что вы хотите. Что вы делаете, то и получаете. Причем здесь ваш вопрос про метод max?

Comment: @ДашаНовикова Метод max находит максимальный элемент массива. Все, что ему нужно, - это целочисленный массив. Вот и передайте ему массив, максимальное значение которого хотите определить.

Comment: Все что мне нужно это получить это максимальное и занести его в переменную, чтобы потом я мог его использовать в других классах

Comment: @ДашаНовикова Ну, так вам уже показано, как это сделать double max = Maximum.max( someArray );

Comment: я же написала, что так приходится вызывать вот такую фигню double max = Maximum.max(Distance.distance(Etalon.etalonMatrix(ConvertToM‌​atrix.convertToMatri‌​x(LoadImage.image("I‌​mages\\1.jpg"))), ConvertToMatrix.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.image("Images\\1.j‌​pg"))));    и в итоге оно много лишнего выведет!

Comment: @ДашаНовикова Я не пойму, а что вы от нас-то хотите?

Answer (score 0):

Вызов переменных класса из вне является не очень хорошей практикой. Получать доступ к полям класса лучше через методы. У тебя такой метод уже реализован. Используй

```
double max = Maximum.max(mass);
```

Answer (score 0):

> я же написала, что так приходится вызывать вот такую фигню double
>   max =
>   Maximum.max(Distance.distance(Etalon.etalonMatrix(ConvertToM‌​‌​atrix.convertToMat‌​ri‌​x(LoadImage.imag‌​e("I‌​mages\1.jpg")‌​)),
>   ConvertToMatrix.convertToMatrix(LoadImage.image("Images\1.j‌​‌​pg"))));
>   и в итоге оно много лишнего выведет

Так передайте ему просто массив! А не это вереницу методов. Настоящая ваша проблема не относится к данному вопросу и нахождению максимального элемента. А является проблемой остального вашего кода. Который вы тут не привели. Создайте новый вопрос или напишите мне лично, помогу вам разобраться. А то тут вам отвечать, репутация не позволяет)